# Can apache-spark read files from NTFS local file system?

Tags: apache-spark, ntfs-3g

This is the function for reading files in spark:

```
def textFile(self, name, minPartitions=None, use_unicode=True):
        """
        file system (available on all
        nodes), or any Hadoop-supported file system URI, and return it as an
        RDD of Strings.

        If use_unicode is False, the strings will be kept as `str` (encoding
        as `utf-8`), which is faster and smaller than unicode. (Added in
        Spark 1.2)

        >>> path = os.path.join(tempdir, "sample-text.txt")
        >>> with open(path, "w") as testFile:
        ...    _ = testFile.write("Hello world!")
        >>> textFile = sc.textFile(path)
        >>> textFile.collect()
        [u'Hello world!']
        """
        minPartitions = minPartitions or min(self.defaultParallelism, 2)
        return RDD(self._jsc.textFile(name, minPartitions), self,
                   UTF8Deserializer(use_unicode))
```